# Is kill function synchronous?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86

Is the `kill` function in Linux synchronous? Say, I programatically call the `kill` function to terminate a process, will it return only when the intended process is terminated, or it just sends the signal and return. If that is the case, how can I make it wait for the intended process to be killed?

Comment: Anecdotally, I can say no, since I've used `kill` on a process, to have it return and have the process still present. Then had to do a `kill -9`.

Comment: Note: not all the signals you can send to a process *will* terminate it - even a `kill 1234` (using `SIGTERM`) can be trapped and bypassed. The only way to unconditionally kill is by using `kill -9`, which is rather brutal (no chance for cleanup).

Comment: Not even `kill -9` always kills it immediately, as there are some states (specifically, state "D") in which it won't die until the kernel thread its tied to finishes.

Comment: kill will terminate a process only at moment when kernel will check incoming signals of target process.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, since it doesn't kill anything, it only sends a signal to the process.

By default this signal can even be blocked or ignored.

You can't block `kill -9` which represents sending `SIGKILL`

To wait for the process to die:

```
while kill -0 PID_OF_THE_PROCESS 2>/dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```

Comment: +1 for showing a simple method of waiting until the pid is gone.

Comment: SIGKILL can't be blocked or ignored by a process. But you're right that the process won't terminate immediately. If a process is doing a system call, it will only end when the system call returns. So if it does some real heavy processing, it may take time.

Comment: It will also refuse to die if it is in the state of `UNINTERRUPTIBLE`

Answer (score 4):

`kill` cannot be synchronous as it only sends a signal. The target process might ignore incoming signals (cf. `SIG_IGN`) so there's no guarantee regarding `kill`'s effect.

It shouldn't be difficult to make an experiment verifying this hypothesis. Start process A and make it handle `SIGTERM` with a 10 second sleep before dying. Then start process B, which delivers a `SIGTERM` to A and exits immediately.

Answer (score 3):

The kill system call does not wait for the other process to do anything.  The signal is posted to the target process and the system call returns.  The target process notices the signal when it is scheduled to run.

Answer (score 2):

1. No. `man 2 kill`
2. `man wait`

See also `man 7 signal` for more details about Unix signals.