# Why not have tomcat stop force as a synchronous operation

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, kill

In Tomcat 7, when the container is stopped using `catalina.sh stop force`, the script uses the CATALINA_PID environment variable to send a kill -9 to the pid of the currently running container process. However, this doesn't kill the [process instantaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762228/is-kill-function-synchronous) - say for e.g. when the process is in the middle of a system call. In this case, why cant we use the ``` kill -0 ``cat "$CATALINA_PID"`` >/dev/null 2>&1 ``` trick that is used with stop in the non-force mode (in catalina.sh)? This would ensure that the `stop force` is synchronous. Just wanted to know if there are good reasons why this was not done.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Logged a [bugzilla enhancement ticket](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54013) with Tomcat for it.

Comment: Do you mean why +can't+ we use that trick? In any case your question can't be answered here. Try the Tomcat developers' mailing list.

Comment: Will also try the dev mailing lists. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `kill -0` does what you think it does. `kill -0` does not synchronously send a signal: it checks to see if you *can* send a signal to a particular process. You still need to send the signal (like `kill -9`). And it will always be asynchronous. Unless you `wait` on the process, except that the process may never complete so you could get hung up.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I was thinking that after issuing the `kill -9`, we can wait for a `KILL_WAIT_INTERVAL` (to ensure a timely end) in a `while` loop checking if the process is still alive (via `kill -0`). Thus the control passes out from the catalina.sh only when 1. the process is no longer alive or 2. it has exceeded its `KILL_WAIT_INTERVAL`. Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably work on Linux, but I think kill -0 is a Linux-only thing.

You can certainly file an enhancement request in [Apache Bugzilla](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/).

Note that it's still not a "synchronous" operation... you're just polling for an expected condition.

Comment: Thanks Christopher for the information. The polling for the expected condition is something that the catalina.sh stop directive also does and there were no OS-specific/arch-specific checks there - so my guess was that the solution would work everywhere. Also the man pages on solaris seem to also indicate support for it. And yes, if this way the stop force operation is just made wait for the expected end condition and is not really-really synchronous. Will try to formulate a working copy of this solution and file a bugzilla request with the changes. Thanks again!