# bash: counter inside a while loop (kill and kill -9)

Tags: bash, scripting, while-loop, kill, kill-process

So I've learnt recently that [kill is not a synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762228/is-kill-function-synchronous) command, so I'm using this while loop in bash, which is awesome:

```
while kill PID_OF_THE_PROCESS 2>/dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```

However, there are cases (very rare, but they still happen) in which the process gets stuck, and it doesn't act on the kill signal. In these cases, the only way to kill the app is using "**kill -9**".

So I'm wondering, how would one modify the while loop above, in bash, to use the -9 argument only if the loop has reached the 10th iteration?

Comment: what's your question? You want to know how to count?

Comment: I want to know how to use a counter inside a while loop in bash, I'm no bash literate

Comment: If you want to know how to create a counter in bash, don't make the question about `kill -9`. That will seriously muddy the waters, since `kill -9` is usually a bad idea, and *definitely* a bad idea to do in a script.

Comment: I seriously considered doing that, but exposing a more generic question (without the "kill" command) would be more difficult to understand... so just including the example of the command I want to use, makes much sense IMHO

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automating Killall then Killall level 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889425/automating-killall-then-killall-level-9)

Comment: @knocte in that case then I have to consider this a possible dupe, since it will be on SO for all posterity for future readers.

Comment: it's not a dupe because: 1) that one is about killall, not kill 2) this one is about sending N kill signals and 1 kill -0, not just one plain "kill"

Comment: Generalized, the `killall` question and this question solve the same problem. If this is not a dupe of it, then it is an overly-narrow question of not much use to future readers and should be closed on those grounds.

Comment: still the other question is about N processes, and this one is about just 1, there may be useful to have two questions around

Answer (score 3):

As other users said.... you have to fix the cause of the block before use this brutal method... anyway... try this

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0

PID_OF_THE_PROCESS="your pid you can set as you like"

# send it just once
kill $PID_OF_THE_PROCESS 2>/dev/null;

while [ $i -lt 10 ];
do
    # still alive?
    [ -d /proc/$PID_OF_THE_PROCESS ] || exit;
    sleep 1;
    i=$((i+1))
done

# 10 iteration loop and still alive? be brutal
kill -9 $PID_OF_THE_PROCESS
```

Comment: was `PID_OF_THE_PROCESS` supposed to be a variable?

Comment: this is almost what I want to achieve! it's only missing the call to "kill" in the previous iterations before the 10th

Comment: @knocte if you send SIGTERM once, it will terminate if it can. Sending it 9 more times is pointless.

Comment: it may be pointless but I want to be sure... (and it may be pointless but it doesn't do any harm right?)

Comment: if you're aware that would be superflous but you want it anyway... just move the kill inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use a counter, but that's a little ham-fisted.

What you probably really want to do is use `0` as your signal, which will do nothing to the process, but let you check if the process is still alive. (`kill -0 $pid` will return a nonzero exit status if the process doesn't exist.) And then, you know, don't just `kill -9` it. Processes don't get stuck for no reason, they get stuck because they can't let go of a resource, such as when network or filesystem blocking occurs. Resolve the block, then the process can clean up after itself.

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate a bit more on the 0 signal? I still don't get the difference between kill and kill -0

Comment: @knocte `kill -0` doesn't do anything to the process if it finds one. It just lets you know that it's there. Think of it like pinging the process to see if it's still alive.

Comment: but plain kill (without -0) also returns a non zero status if it doesn't exist, so this doesn't improve anything really

Comment: @knocte in this case it's not all that useful, but the premise behind the script itself is dicey, which is why this answer is about how to avoid using `kill -9` altogether.

Comment: @knocte one final point to consider: What if your SIGTERM kills the process successfully in the first iteration, but another, unrelated process you don't want to kill gets spawned with the same pid?

Comment: sounds very rare thing to happen, no? like two new guids colliding

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to send the signal once.

```
kill $PID 2>/dev/null
sleep 10;
if kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null
  kill -9 $PID
fi
```

For your counter question:

```
c=0
while true; do
    echo $c;
    c=$((c+1));
    if [ $c -eq 10 ]; then break; fi;
done
```

Comment: I said 10th iteration, not 10 seconds

Comment: alright, if you combine both code blocks in one I'll upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, but you did ask to modify your existing loop, so:

```
count=0
while kill PID_OF_THE_PROCESS 2>/dev/null
do 
    sleep 1; 
    (( count++ ))
    if (( count > 9 ))
    then
        kill -9 PID_OF_THE_PROCESS 2>/dev/null
     fi
done
```

Comment: can you just add an elif to kill the process in the N iteration if count < 10?